# Micronaut MySQL delete record org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, hibernate, micronaut

Using Micronaut Groovy GROM I was able to read the data from MySQL database. but when I try to delete the record its throwing `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread` error message.

```
curl -s http://localhost:8880/book/1
{"bookid":"1","name":"Java","id":1}

curl -s http://localhost:8880/book/delete/1
{"message":"Internal Server Error: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread"}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
    package webapp

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Delete
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import io.micronaut.spring.tx.annotation.Transactional;

@Slf4j
//@CompileStatic
@Controller("/book")
class BookController implements BooksApi {

    final BookService bookService

    BookController(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService
    }

    @Get("/list")
    List<Book> listBooks() {
        return bookService.findAll()
    }


    @Get("/count")
    int Count(){
        return bookService.count()
    }

    @Override
    @Get("/{id}")
    Book show(Long id) {
        return bookService.find(id)
    }

    @Delete("/{id}")
    Book delete(Long id) {
        Book b= bookService.find(id)
        if(b){
       // b.delete(flush: true)
        b.delete()
        }
        return b
    }


   @Post("/save")
   def save(@Body Object JSON) {
    String bookid=JSON?.bookid
    String name=JSON?.name


    def b =bookService.save(bookid,name)
    return HttpResponse.created(b)

   }

   @Get("/")
    String index() {
        return "Hello World"
    }

}
```

May I know what I am doing wrong here?

thanks

**Updated Code 1**
BookService

```
package webapp

import grails.gorm.services.Service

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional;


@Service(Book)
interface BookService {

    int count()
    Book save(@NotBlank String bookid,@NotBlank String name)
    List<Book> findAll()
    Book find(@NotNull Long id)

    @Transactional
    Book delete(@NotNull Long id)

    void deleteById(Long id)
}
```

Comment: Is `BookService` annotated with `grails.gorm.services.Service`?

Comment: btw... Deleting data in response to a `GET` request is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Move the `@Transactional` annotation into `BookService` and annotate, as required, the desired methods. If you are using version `1.0.0` it does not work at class level – as it's with Spring Boot, for instance.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes I have included `grails.gorm.services.Service` annotation. also changed request to delete.

Comment: @x80486 moved  `@Transcational` to service class, still getting the same error. using `1.0.2` version

Comment: Moving `@Transactional` to the service class won't help.  GORM data services are made Transactional by default and if you remove it from your controller action, the delete will be happing outside of a transaction.  A better idea is to move the deleting into he service.

Comment: Why are you calling `b.delete()` instead of `bookService.delete(id)`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, you might be right. I didn't pay attention and this is a GORM data service which I'm not super familiar with ;) ...I was referring to a Java/Kotlin based service class.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks, I have changed it now its working let me update the code

Comment: also from my controller from spring changed to GORM transaction class `grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional`

Comment: If you move the transactional stuff into the GORM data service, you won't need to use any `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yeah I have removed the `@Transcational` now. its working fine

Comment: @sfgroups awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from Jeff Brown, I make it working. Here is the working code.

Service:

```
package webapp

import grails.gorm.services.Service

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

@Service(Book)
interface BookService {
    int count()

    Book save(@NotBlank String bookid, @NotBlank String name)

    List<Book> findAll()

    Book find(@NotNull Long id)

    Book delete(@NotNull Long id)    
}
```

**Controller**

```
package webapp

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*

@Slf4j
//@CompileStatic
@Controller("/book")
class BookController implements BooksApi {

    final BookService bookService

    BookController(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService
    }

    @Get("/list")
    List<Book> listBooks() {
        return bookService.findAll()
    }

    @Get("/count")
    int Count() {
        return bookService.count()
    }

    @Override
    @Get("/{id}")
    Book show(Long id) {
        return bookService.find(id)
    }

    @Delete("/{id}")
    Book delete(Long id) {
        return bookService.delete(id)
    }

    @Post("/save")
    def save(@Body Object JSON) {
        String bookid = JSON?.bookid
        String name = JSON?.name
        def b = bookService.save(bookid, name)
        return HttpResponse.created(b)
    }

    @Get("/")
    String index() {
        return "Book Service"
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "4.0.2"    
}

apply plugin:"application"
apply plugin:"groovy"

version "0.1"
group "webapp"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:1.0.2'
    }
}

ext {
    gormVersion = '6.1.9.RELEASE'
    h2Version = '1.4.196'
    tomcatJdbcVersion = '8.5.28'
    springSecurityCryptoVersion='4.2.5.RELEASE'
}

dependencies {
    compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-jdbc-tomcat"
    compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-validator"
    compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-gorm"
    compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5:$gormVersion"

    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime-groovy"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    compile "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    runtime "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    testCompile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }

    runtime "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.9.Final"
    runtime group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.13'

}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

run.jvmArgs('-noverify', '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1')

mainClassName = "webapp.Application"
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    groovyOptions.forkOptions.jvmArgs.add('-Dgroovy.parameters=true')
}
```

**application.yaml file**

```
---
micronaut:
    application:
        name: webapp
    server:
        port: 8880

---
datasources.default: {}
---
hibernate:
  hbm2ddl:
    auto: update
  cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: true
    use_query_cache: false
    region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
dataSource:
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
  dbCreate: create-update
  pooled: true
  jmxExport: true
  driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
  username:  
  password:
```

Hope this helps others.

Thanks